# Duplicate key exception in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is simple code which add new entity to sql server using EF

```
   var isNewEntity = entity.Id == 0;

        if (isNewEntity)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Context.DbTripReportDefinitionSectionSet.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectStateEntry stateEntry;
            _unitOfWork.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out stateEntry);

            if (stateEntry == null)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Context.DbTripReportDefinitionSectionSet.Attach(entity);
            }

            _unitOfWork.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        _unitOfWork.Save();

        return entity.Id;
```

The problem is i have an exception

> 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.' for already exists but not tracked entity.

So `_unitOfWork.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out stateEntry);` return false and this code `_unitOfWork.Context.DbTripReportDefinitionSectionSet.Attach(entity);` throw exception. I guess because of navigation properties which already attached. How can i  attach these entity without navigation properties? Or how can i resolve these problem in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I may advise you to create a new `Context` instance.

Most probably your assumption about navigation properties is right; but instead of trying to fix the code, it is better for you to create a new `context` unless there are operations which require to be committed in the same transaction (I am assuming you are employing unit of work pattern).